# py.test conftest - Modify Fixture Parameter Based on sys.argv

Tags: python, selenium, pytest

I have a working pytest environment for Selenium testing. I use a parameterized fixture in conftest.py that allows me to test all the different browsers without having to rewrite the test. I'd like to pass a command line argument to my script so that I can have it run only a specific browser, rather than all of them. To do this, I would need to modify the variables passed into my fixture. So far, I haven't been able to figure out how to do this. My example below doesn't work, likely because pytest parses the conftest.py seperately from the variable my startup script describes.

```
#conftest.py
browsers = { "ff" : webdriver.Firefox, "ie" : webdriver.Ie }
@pytest.yield_fixture(params=browsers.keys())
def browser(request):
    driver = browsers[request.param]()
    yield driver
    driver.quit()

#test_simple.py
def test_simple(browser):
    browser.get("http://stackoverflow.com")

#main.py
browsers = {}
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
            if arg == "-ff":
                browsers = { "ff" : webdriver.Firefox }
            elif arg == "-ie":
                browsers = { "ie" : webdriver.Ie }
            elif arg == "-all":
                browsers = { "ff" : webdriver.Firefox, "ie" : webdriver.Ie }

    pytest.main()
```

---

**How can I pass values to a parameterized fixture in conftest.py?**

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See: [Pass different values to a test function, depending on command line options](http://pytest.org/latest/example/simple.html#pass-different-values-to-a-test-function-depending-on-command-line-options).

You can't actually change parametrization using command-line options because parametrization definition occurs during import, but you can easily skip tests for other browsers if the user specifies one in the command line:

```
# conftest.py
import pytest

browsers = {"ff": 'FIREFOX', 'ie': 'INTERNETEXPLORER'}

def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption("--browser", default='',
        type='choice', choices=sorted(browsers),
        help="runs tests only for given browser")    

@pytest.yield_fixture(params=browsers.keys())
def browser(request):
    selected = request.config.getoption('browser')
    if selected and selected != request.param:
        pytest.skip('browser {} selected in the command line'.format(selected))
    driver = browsers[request.param]
    yield driver
```

With this, when the user runs `pytest` without passing any value to `--browser`, all tests run as usual:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.6 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.7.0.dev1 -- X:\temp\sandbox\.env27\Scripts\python.exe
plugins: xdist
collecting ... collected 2 items

test_simple.py::test_simple[ie] PASSED
test_simple.py::test_simple[ff] PASSED

========================== 2 passed in 0.01 seconds ===========================
```

But if the user for example passes `--browser=ie`, firefox tests are then skipped:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 2.7.6 -- py-1.4.26 -- pytest-2.7.0.dev1 -- X:\temp\sandbox\.env27\Scripts\python.exe
plugins: xdist
collecting ... collected 2 items

test_simple.py::test_simple[ie] PASSED
test_simple.py::test_simple[ff] SKIPPED

===================== 1 passed, 1 skipped in 0.01 seconds =====================
```

Comment: I've read over the docs and implemented some of the examples but I haven't been able to get it to work correctly. The problem is that I need to pass the dictionary keys with my browsers to the browser fixture, but there isn't an obvious way to check the command line option and update the browsers dictionary so that the appropriate keys are available to the fixture before the browsers fixture actual runs.

Answer (score 1):

Just use ENV variables:

```
#conftest.py
browsers = { "ff" : webdriver.Firefox, "ie" : webdriver.Ie }
@pytest.yield_fixture(params=browsers.keys())
def browser(request):
    driver = browsers[request.param]()
    yield driver
    driver.quit()

#test_simple.py
def test_simple(browser):
    browser.get("http://stackoverflow.com")

#main.py
browsers = {}
browserToRun = os.environ.get('BROWSER_TO_RUN')
if __name__ == "__main__":
            if browserToRun == "ff":
                browsers = { "ff" : webdriver.Firefox }
            elif browserToRun == "ie":
                browsers = { "ie" : webdriver.Ie }
            elif browserToRun == "all":
                browsers = { "ff" : webdriver.Firefox, "ie" : webdriver.Ie }

    pytest.main()
```

and run tests like:

`BROWSER_TO_RUN=ff run_tests.py`

Answer (score 0):

```
 pytest -k test_simple['ie']
```

Above line will selectively run matched test